# How to show collection of all nonempty bounded closed subsets of a metric space is also complete with respect to Hausdorff metric.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a complete metric space. Let $\mathcal M$ be the collection of all nonempty bounded closed subsets of $M$ endowed with Hausdorff metric $H$.

How to show $(\mathcal M,H)$ is also complete?

Can anyone please give me some hints to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the usual way to get started: let $\{K_j\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\cal M$.  Define $K$ to be the set of all $x \in M$ with the property that there is a sequence $\{x_j\} \in M$ satisfying

1. $x_j \in K_j$ for all $j$, and
2. $x_j \to x$.

The result is that $H(K_j,K) \to 0$ so that $K_j \to K$ in the metric $H$.

Comment: 1) So $\{K_j\}$ Cauchy implies $\{x_j\}$ Cauchy?
2) Why be $K$ a bounded closed subset of $M$?

Comment: And how does the result you stated follows?

Comment: These are the details that need to be worked out. You asked for a hint to get started.